# How to force Amazon Elastic Beanstalk get-config to quote all strings when ouputting as YAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, xargs

I am exporting all AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment variables and piping the output to serve as command line arguments using xargs.

```
export $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config --output YAML environment | sed -r 's/: /=/' | xargs)
```

Most strings in the YAML output from `get-config` are not quoted, so the above command snippet breaks when it encounters any environment variable with a space in its value, because the `export` command uses spaces to delimit the beginning of a new key-value pair.

For example, say I have an environment variable called TEST_VARIABLE with a value of `THIS STRING`. The above command fails with an error:

```
-bash: export: `THIS STRING': not a valid identifier
```

In essence, my question is, how do I get `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config --output YAML environment` to quote all strings?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be using below env.yaml file as example (I don't use AWS BS so I don't know if there would be a heavy syntax difference), next time please provide an edited example:

### env.yaml

```yaml
env1: this the 1st
env2: this the 2nd
```

In any case, piping to `xargs` will be hard for quotes to be kept (as they'd end up being interpreted by a shell, but then you'd need to re-quote them).

You should instead try to produce equivalent (several) export lines, to be consumed by the running shell, something on the lines of `source <( output with several export x="..." lines)` (valid syntax  for `bash`, `zsh`, and maybe others).

Pasting below two possibilities:

### using only `sed`

Below solution works (I chose single quotes), on the assumption that there's no single-quoted value.

```shell
$ sed -E "s/(.+): (.+)/export \1='\2'/" env.yaml
export env1='this the 1st'
export env2='this the 2nd'
$ source <(sed -E "s/(.+): (.+)/export \1='\2'/" env.yaml)
$ env|egrep ^env
env1=this the 1st
env2=this the 2nd
```

### using `yq`

Use https://github.com/kislyuk/yq for the needed quoting then sed for the `:` substitution:

```shell
$ yq '.. style="single"' env.yaml|sed -e 's/^/export /' -e 's/: /=/'
export env1='this the 1st'
export env2='this the 2nd'
$ source <(yq '.. style="single"' env.yaml|sed -e 's/^/export /' -e 's/: /=/')
$ env|egrep ^env
env1=this the 1st
env2=this the 2nd
```